# Interfacing Qt application with Scilab via call_scilab (Scilab API)

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtcore, scilab

I'm working on Qt application, that has to compute some data using Scilab's numerical engine. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 with installed Scilab v.5.5.0 and QtCreator v.3.2.1 (Qt 5.3.2).

I'm using a simple code example provided in scilab help:

```
   /****** INITIALIZATION **********/
#ifdef _MSC_VER
 if ( StartScilab(NULL,NULL,NULL) == FALSE )
#else
 if ( StartScilab(getenv("SCI"),NULL,NULL) == FALSE )
#endif
  {
   fprintf(stderr,"Error while calling StartScilab\n");

  }

/****** ACTUAL Scilab TASKS *******/

 SendScilabJob("myMatrix=['sample','for the help']");
 SendScilabJob("disp(myMatrix);"); // Will display !sample  for the help  !
 SendScilabJob("disp([2,3]+[-44,39]);"); // Will display   - 42.    42.

/****** TERMINATION **********/
 if ( TerminateScilab(NULL) == FALSE ) {
  fprintf(stderr,"Error while calling TerminateScilab\n");

 }
```

My problem is that after clicking "Run", I get an alert as follows:

/home/med/Dokumenty/QTWorkspace/build-QTtest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_GCC_32bit-Debug/QTtest: error while loading shared libraries: libscicall_scilab.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to add following line to qmake .pro file, but without any results:

```
LIBS += /usr/lib/scilab/libscicall_scilab.so.5
```

The library already is in specified dir (I've checked this manually). Before that I was trying a lot of another settings - still without success.

Could anyone provide the proper solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the location of your lib to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your project file:

```
LIBS = -L/usr/lib/scilab -lscicall_scilab
```

You will need to rerun qmake then to regenerate the Makefile(s). Make sure that you have 32 bit library of scilab or change the build to 64 bit should that be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've added:

LIBS = -L/usr/lib/scilab -lscicall_scilab

to my .pro file and then started QMake. After that I've got similar message for libjavasci2.so.5

What is very interesting, when I've added:

LIBS = -L/usr/lib/jni/libjavasci2.so.5.5.0

there is problem with scicall_scilab again... How can I check if my library installed is 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @medicaldev: `LIBS = -L/usr/lib/jni/libjavasci2.so.5.5.0` is overriding the LIBS variable as it is not appending. If you want to preserve the previous value, use `+=`, not `=`. Please stop using full paths those and disassemble them into path and library name.

Comment: Right, I've changed to: LIBS += -L/usr/lib/scilab -lscicall_scilab and LIBS += -L/usr/lib/jni -ljavasci (or ljavasci2, no difference). Now the message is about libjava.so (in both cases)... I'm not familiar with dynamical libraries under Linux.

Comment: @medicaldev: so have you resolved the LIBS usage for all the libraries that your project is using?

Comment: I've linked all the required libs, including those from Java JDK (by the way, not specified in Scilab help). So now that's ok. Now I have another problem. After running my application (finally!), first used function from API returned message "SCI not found". I've checked some system paths Scilab is related to. Also, I've checked scilab-adv-cli, scilab-cli and scilab-bin - all of these executables run correctly when called manually from the terminal. I will be trying to connect using api, but now the only way is to call scilab through system() function, with use of external .sci file.

Comment: @medicaldev: that is a different question. Do not try to solve a whole in one SO question... [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).